# SSH to Ubuntu virtual machine under Azure, permission denied (publickey)

Tags: networking, server, permissions, ssh, azure

We do have a virtual Ubuntu machine under Azure. The IP address is known (for this message it will be named "thatIP").

Setup to log in via a certificate does work.

We are now trying to set up an access using username/password. SSH access is from a macOS machine (called "mylocal" in this message).

Already done and tried:

- created the user "myuser" on the virtual machine
- created ssh keys on mylocal (as described in various cases)
- transferred public key to myuser@thatIP … lead to *INFO: 1 key(s) remain to be installed -- if you are prompted now it is to install the new keys* followed by *Permission denied (publickey)*
- manually created the .ssh directories for myuser and manually copied the .pub file to the right place
- attempting to log in using via ssh … lead to the Permission denied (publickey) error.
- starting to scratch head…

I am not familiar with the Azure environment, but my business partner is kind of…

From what I see, the connection should work. But I may miss something, either on the Ubuntu VM, or the Azure machine.

Any advice, lead etc. is highly appreciated.

Comment: I do see no mention of [authorized_keys](https://askubuntu.com/search?q=authorized_keys+ssh) which seems needed AFAIK

Comment: It would be helpful to provide specifics, rather than things like *"to the right place"* that are open to interpretation. As well, publickey is a different authentication mechanism from username/password - which is it that you are trying to set up? One common gotcha for publickey is overly permissive access modes on the authorized_keys file or its parent directory.

Answer (score 0):

The problem could be solved by activating the password authentification in the config file.

Thanks for all the comments.